# Unable to see login profile in console using token based api

Tags: reactjs

hello everyone i trying to login with django api...i have successfully logged into dashboard...but i am unable to get profile data of login user...the response is credentials are not provided...its token based authentication...can any one help on these...

dashboard.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';


    class Dashboard extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                id: '',
                user_profile: '',
                created_on: '',
                token: this.props.cookies.get('Token')
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {

            if (this.state.token) {

                fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed/", {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': `${this.state.token}`
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => response.data)
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.response.data)
                    })
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '/'
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="Dashboard" >
                    <div>Dashboard</div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default withCookies(Dashboard);
```

Comment: You can't use `this.props` in the constructor like that, just use `props.cookies`. What cookie manager are you using, `react-cookie`? Is that what's providing `withCookie` and thus the `cookies` prop? Can you `console.log(props.cookies.get('Token')` in the constructor (or in componentDidMount) to verify it returns a value? Have you verified the token cookie is set upon authentication?

Comment: thanks very very much Drew..for asking this question (Have you verified the token cookie is set upon authentication?)....with that i got some solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to verify the token is present in the main div

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'


class Dashboard extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            user_profile: '',
            created_on: '',
            token: this.props.cookies.get("Token")
        }
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.token) {
            fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed/", {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Token ${this.state.token}`
                }
            })
                .then(response => response.data)
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error.response.data)
                })
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = '/'
        }
    }

    logout = (e) => {
        const { cookies } = this.props;
        cookies.remove('Token');
        window.location.href = '/';
        // return false;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Dashboard" token={this.state.token}>
                <div>Dashboard</div>
                <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
                <NavLink to="/status">
                    <button>
                        Status Page
                    </button>
                </NavLink>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withCookies(Dashboard);
```